# Why does sorted(by:) work but sort(by:) does not in ForEach loop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to show a list of custom objects in an ordered manner.
While this works...

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let timestamp: Date
}

struct ViewModel {
    var models = [
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(300)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(100)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(500))
    ]
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.models.sorted(by: { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in // will not work with `sort(by:)`
                lhs.timestamp > rhs.timestamp
            })) { model in
                Text("\(model.timestamp)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                //delete from viewModel.models
            })
        }
    }
}
```

...it falls short when deleting, because the array I am working on is not sorted (only it's visualisation, so to say).

`sort(by:)` should be what I need, as it "Sorts the collection in place, using the given predicate as the comparison between elements." according to Apple's documentation.

However, the same `ForEach` statement will not work for `sort(by:)`, throwing the error `Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'`.

Is there a way to sort in place and loop with `ForEach` in this case or will I have to handle sorting in my `ViewModel`?

Comment: one is a mutating function the other returns a new array. If you want to sort your array only once you should do it in your view model

Comment: Ok, understood. After having mutated, can I get hold of the mutated array in line though?

Comment: Mutating here means as the documentation says that it is the original array that gets sorted so you already have it.

Comment: That's what I thought as well – still, I cannot loop over it with `ForEach` which should be possible imo.

Comment: @ASSeeger Why should it be possible? The return type of `Void` (a.k.a. the empty tuple, `()`). Iterating over that is no different than `for i in print("hello world")`: it makes no sense. You're looking for the non-mutating version, why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you can't use `sort(by:)` inside the `ForEach` is because `sort(by:)` is a mutating function that returns `Void`. `sorted(by:)` on the other hand returns a new array that you can iterate through with the `ForEach`.

You can solve your problem by creating a separate computed property on `ViewModel`, which return `models` sorted and calling `ForEach` with this sorted properties. You just need to make sure you also perform deletion on the sorted array.

```
struct ViewModel {
    var models = [
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(300)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(100)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(500))
    ]

    var sortedModels: [MyModel] {
        get {
            models.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp })
        }
        set {
            models = newValue
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sortedModels) { model in
                Text("\(model.timestamp)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                for index in indexSet {
                    viewModel.sortedModels.remove(at: index)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks. I guess I could also write an extension on Collection to have a `sort(by:) -> [Element]`, I guess (theoretically speaking).

Comment: That's a bit overkill @LeoDabus, a more pragmatic solution would be to sort in the setter (assuming the initial collection is already sorted). Getters should be O(1)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen the getter shown here will sort the collection every time he calls this property anyway.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Btw if the collection is already sorted you don't need to sort it again after removing elements. I would also reverse the indices when removing the elements.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a computed property. You can simply sort the models when your list appears. No need to sort it every time you delete a model if they are already sorted. You should also conform your model to comparable protocol:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.models) {
                Text("\($0.timestamp)")
            }
            .onDelete {
                $0.reversed().forEach { viewModel.models.remove(at: $0) }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            viewModel.models.sort(by: >)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MyModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let timestamp: Date
}

extension MyModel: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.timestamp < rhs.timestamp
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ViewModel {
    var models = [
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(300)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(100)),
        MyModel(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(500))
    ]
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually a good point! I decided to do sorting in the ViewModel cause I suppose that's the better spot (when trying to stick to MVVM) – but using `.onAppear` might come in handy in other instances.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other two answers, I'd like to add some more information regards how you're meant to use ViewModels.

Essentially you want to have a ViewModel that is a `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property for the values you expect to change. That way you can encapsulate any important logic inside the ViewModel.

Having a struct ViewModel doesn't make any sense, as structs aren't mutable.

Furthermore you can implement `Comparable` on your model type, allowing you to have sorting tied to the type, rather than at random places in your code. Now how it's also not necessary to re-sort the content when you delete individual models if your model is already sorted.

And if you had inserts, you would want to sort them when inserting.

And finally, you should only use `@State` variables for UI state, not (View)Model state.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyModel: Identifiable, Equatable, Comparable {
    let id = UUID()
    let timestamp: Date

    static func < (lhs: MyModel, rhs: MyModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timestamp > rhs.timestamp
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    private(set) var models: [MyModel]

    init() {
        let now = Date()
        models = [
            MyModel(timestamp: now.addingTimeInterval(300)),
            MyModel(timestamp: now.addingTimeInterval(100)),
            MyModel(timestamp: now.addingTimeInterval(500))
        ].sorted()
    }

    func remove(at indicies: IndexSet) {
        indicies.forEach { index in
            models.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.models) { model in
                Text("\(model.timestamp)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                viewModel.remove(at: indexSet)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my ViewModel should be a class – makes perfect sense... In the original project I tried to abstract from to have a good example for SO, I do use a class, but thanks to you I now do know why this is key.